# KeyError: "None of [] are in the columns"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

I am trying to execute the following code that converts a ismr file to a python data frame. The method read_ismr returns a python data frame.

I keep on getting the following exception. 
"KeyError: "None of ['Time'] are in the columns"". Where time is supposed to be one of the expected columns of the data frame.

```
import pandas
import ismrpy
data=ismrpy.read_ismr("sacc17001a.ismr")
print(data)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

With respect,
Chintan Thakrar

Comment: What does `print(data)` return?

Comment: It does not get to that line. The code terminated before it gets to that file. The exception is raised from the above line. Nothing but the exception is printed to the console.

Comment: In order to get help you'll need to show the full error and trace back

Comment: @Jason please a link to the screenshot of the code and the error below. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P7G-Zo3ohMFX9Jf8T_Ga6GJwyzNEsEno
with respect,

Comment: @Jason, please find a link to the screenshot of the code and the error below
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P7G-Zo3ohMFX9Jf8T_Ga6GJwyzNEsEno
with respect

Comment: The problem is because the method `ismrpy.read_ismr()` expected to find a column in your data `sacc17001a.ismr` that is called exactly `Date` (with a capital 'D'). To fix the error you'll need to check the contents of `sacc17001a.ismr` and edit name whichever column has the dates as `Date`.

Comment: hello, after further debugging i figured out that error. But again I encounter a different error https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P7G-Zo3ohMFX9Jf8T_Ga6GJwyzNEsEno any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: @Jason any ideas?